# Error in compilation when using Try-with-Resources

Tags: java

I am a newbie on Java and writing a code of Try-with-Resources. I am using JRE_1.7.0_51. The code is...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class app2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file=new File("test.txt");
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);

        try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr)){

        }

     }
}
```

However post execution I get the following eror--

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token "(", { expected
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

    at App.main(App.java:13)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `at App.main(App.java:13)` This is not the code you're showing.

Comment: The error shows it's in App.java. But the code snippet shows the class app2!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What compiler are you using? The only thing missing is a check for `IOException`. The following code compiles without problems

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class app2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file=new File("test.txt");
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);

        try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr)){

        }

     }
}
```

Comment: Hi I ran the above code as well, but I still get the following error. Additionally I am using eclispse helios as editor-- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token "(", { expected
 Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
 Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
 Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement

 at app2.main(app2.java:11)